# Server creates file on-the-fly for client to save

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, file-io

**THE EXAMPLE**

**1)** User enters in a playlist in a `<textarea>`

- C:/music/foo.mp3
- C:/music/bar.mp3
- C:/music/hello.mp3

**2)** They click a *save* button. I send the user's playlist to the server with AJAX.

**3)** The server formats the text with PHP in this fashion:

```
<playlist>
 <item>C:/music/foo.mp3</item>
 <item>C:/music/bar.mp3</item>
 <item>C:/music/hello.mp3</item>
</playlist>
```

**4)** A file save dialog pops up asking the user to save this formatted text as *playlist.m3u* on their own harddrive.

---

**QUESTIONS**

**A)** Is it possible to not write a file to the harddrive on the server when generating this m3u file? I don't want millions of files clogging up my server. I suppose PHP can echo out the formatted text and set headers to masquerade as a file.

**B)** How do I get the file save dialog to pop up for this *on-the-fly* file? If it were a real file, I would just have the PHP respond back with the location of the file. Then I would have JS insert a new iFrame with that location. But I don't want to write a file on the server, so I can't do this.

```
new Ajax.Request(
 'generateM3u.php',
 onSuccess: function(transport) {
  $$('body').first().appendChild(
   new Element(
    'iframe', {
     src: transport.responseText
    }
   )
  );
 }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php from the PHP manual. There are a lot of user contributions at the bottom of the page regarding forcing the browser to show a download prompt rather than printing to screen.

Here is one from that page ([By phpnet at holodyn dot com 31-Jan-2011 09:01](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#102175)) which I have edited slightly. I think it answers both questions A and B. Just send the textbox's contents to the PHP file through an iframe, allow it to format the text appropriately and send it back to the browser with the following headers.

```
$contents = '<playlist>etc....</playlist>';

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: audio/x-mpegurl");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"playlist.m3u\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $contents;
```

**Edit:** If what you want is an all Javascript solution, then I personally don't know, and after a little google-ing, it looks like others don't either. Most seem to solve this with an invisible iframe that directs to a server-side file.

**Edit 2:** I've changed the content type so that it matches the m3u file type.

Comment: This works, but there's one small detail that's wrong. The dialog pops up saying: `You have chosen to open playlist.m3u which is a GIF Image from http://192.168.0.81`. It's not critical, but it's weird that it says GIF.

Comment: Okay then that just means you gotta change the Content-Type header. The mime type for m3u is audio/x-mpegurl. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why the browser thought it was a GIF. The code did not actually mention what type of file it was at all (other than the file extension) so it should have just said 'unknown type' if it didn't recognise the extension. That's strange.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a form on your parent DOM, and post it to the IFRAME/pop-up that you created?

The POST action URL will be your generateMu3.php

To answer your questions,

A & B) I assume so... as long as generateM3u.php sets the correct MIMEType for the .m3u file...

I'm not familiar with syntax in PHP, but in both Java & .NET, you can set the response's MIMEType in the header to, say, a Word document, and the browser will read the header, and if it's a file that is "Save-able", it'll prompt the client to save the page as a file.

Comment: I seem the recall this technique when I did fake "AJAX" image upload.

Comment: @JoJo - Yea. It's a common technique for file upload as well. "Like" your quotes around AJAX. =D

Comment: So this is a little different from the fake "Ajax" image upload. In the image upload, the iFrame's HTML is filled with the server location of the uploaded image. It doesn't pop up a file dialog save for the image.

Comment: Oh nevermind. When you echo with the right headers, it pops up the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly there's a machine creating the .m3u files. In that case, perhaps just write the files to a temporary directory, `/tmp` on unix machines and`C:\Windows\Temp` on Windows machines. Those files are cleared on boot, which should allow you to handle **B)** without all the **A)**.

Comment: He mentioned that he would rather not save the files to the disk.  If he wrote to /tmp, then he would also have to make a symlink to the document_root directory of his webserver.  Also webservers don't get rebooted often so these files could accumulate for a while.